# incrementing variable in SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a problem with the following code. The variable $entry never becomes greater than 1. I want it to increment to be able to take all keywords and put them in a single variable. I can't find the reason why $entry is being incremented. Thanks in advance! :-)

```
function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $entry, $arrSkipIndices = array()) {

`$arrData = array();`
$kwords=array();

// if input is object, convert into array

if (is_object($arrObjData)) {

    $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);

}

if (is_array($arrObjData)) {


    foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {

    if ($index=="keywordterm"&&$index!="0"){
        $kword=$arrObjData[$index];
        //echo "arrObjData[$index]: ".$kword."</br></br>";
        $kwords[$entry]=$kword;
        //echo "keywords: ".$kwords."</br></br>";
        //echo "keywords[$entry]: ".$kwords[$entry]."</br></br>";
        $entry++;

    }
        if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {

            $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $entry, $arrSkipIndices); // recursive call

        }

        if (in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices)) {
            continue;
        }

        $arrData[$index] = $value;
        //echo "$arrData[$index]: ".$arrData[$index]."</br>";
    }


}

return $arrData;
}

`$entry=0;

$xmlUrl = "9424.xml"; // XML feed file/URL

$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

$arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj, $entry);`
```

With the 1st execution it shows:
keywords[0]: telecommunication computing

With the 2nd it shows:
keywords[0]: multi-agent systems

You see? It's 0 again....

A little code from the xml:

```
<keywordset keywordtype="Inspec">
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[telecommunication computing]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[multi-agent systems]]></keywordterm>
       </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[state estimation]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[control engineering computing]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
      <keyword>
        <keywordterm><![CDATA[telecommunication control]]></keywordterm>
      </keyword>
    </keywordset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but one thing I have noticed is that you are attempting to change the params without a reference to an object.

Change

```
function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $entry, $arrSkipIndices = array()) {
```

To

```
function objectsIntoArray(&$arrObjData, &$entry, $arrSkipIndices = array()) {
```

It may, or may not help; but its something to try.

Example of what I mean...

```
function IncNumber($num)
{
    $num++;
}

$num = 0;
IncNumber($num);
// $num will still be 0



// Using & to declare a reference to the object
function IncNumber2(&$num)
{
    $num++;
}
IncNumber2($num);
// $num will be 1
```

Comment: thank you!! It works fine!! I couldn't imagine that would cause such a problem... Do you know exactly why? you say I am attempting to change the params without a reference to an object. That's why the entry variable wouldn't change? Thank you again!!

Comment: @ApostolosKou, if this has helped and it is the correct answer, would you be able to mark as the correct answer, by clicking the tick next to my answer? This would also help in the future if you have any further questions, as it boosts your acceptance rating. Many Thanks

Comment: @ApostolosKou, if you dont specify a & it'll basically copy the object, so its de-allocated from the original memory. By using &, it references the object directly, rather than copying it.